# Survival Analysis in Python - Is there any survminer equivalent in Python?

Tags: survival-analysis, survival, lifelines, survminer

I am a Data Scientist who is an avid R user and currently exploring Python if it helps to broaden my analytics reach. As a first step, I am trying to replicate my current R analyses using Python. Having worked in oncology, I frequently perform survival analyses using the time to event data. R has a very strong toolset to analyze and plot time to event data eg. survival and survminer. I am using the lifelines package in python but I found it not as elegant as survminer (ggsurvplot) especially when it comes to visualization. Just wanted to hear from others if they felt the same and have found any solution to tackle this. I am also open to volunteer if someone has the bandwidth to develop survminer equivalent in python.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a python package, [surpyval](https://surpyval.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) that I think is a little more user friendly than other python implementations. It has some good visualisations that might help you out, also it is very easy to use with matplotlib.

Would be happy to make changes that makes it closer to survminer.